# What are the causes of a "REACHABLE_CONSTRAINT" response from a Request to The tour planing API v3.6

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to understand why this given geolocation cant be routed:
route should start at this point:

```
"location": {
            "lat": -30.02897115,
            "lng": -51.22483528
            }
```

and end at this point:

```
"location": {
            "lat": -30.03011,
            "lng": -51.22804
            }
```

The first point is standard for many other routes without this error, so my team and I are assuming the problem is with the end location. Since the documentation doesn't mention this specific error, I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for REACHABLE_CONSTRAINT error is the location is not reachable. It can be because there is no road that exists to reach that location by the given vehicle. If live traffic mode is used, it can happen due to temporary road closure or traffic incident which makes the location not reachable by the given vehicle. If avoid feature is also used in the fleet profile, that can lead to road restrictions for the vehicle and therefore, can make the location unreachable. Please, check your problem file or provide more details for further analysis.

Comment: I have the same problem. A few weeks ago API returned this error and today is happening again (I don't know if meanwhile was happening because I switched to another project). If I navigate the address corresponding to the coordinates in here maps nothing is mentioned about the destination being  unreachable. Is this something related to tour planning API? I am using v.3.9.0